# Are measurements using the first fundamental form preserved by re-parameterization?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

I may be conflating a number of different concepts, but I am confused about measurements using the first fundamental form.

Here is what I think I know:

1. The [first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form) can be used to compute distance on a parametric surface
2. The coefficients of the first fundamental form can be re-parameterized through substitution, as with the relation given in [Sec. 1.3 here](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/348.A1.16f/L08_20161004.pdf).

Here is what confuses me:

1. Re-parameterizing the sphere through a map projection (e.g. gnomonic projection, mercator projection, etc.) results in different distances on the mapped surface. That is, $ds_{map}^2 \ne ds_{sphere}^2$. I can walk through this derivation and it makes logical sense.
2. Yet, "arclength is invariant to coordinate system transformations," at least according to the proof on the [Metric Tensor Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Invariance_of_arclength_under_coordinate_transformations) (screenshot pasted below) and a handful of other Google search results on the topic. But isn't a spherical projection a coordinate transformation $M : (\lambda, \phi) \rightarrow (x, y)$?

[image]

I believe that [this text](https://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/diff_geom.pdf) clears it up a bit (bottom of page 8):

> A mapping of a portion of a manifold M to a portion of a manifold N is called isometric, if the length of any curve on N is the same as the length of its pre-image on M.

In other words, arclength is preserved by isometric transformations. Spherical map projections are provably not isometric, so, sure, that's why  $ds_{map}^2 \ne ds_{sphere}^2$. I think I follow this.

Why I'm confused is because I thought I followed the logic of proof on the Wikipedia page, and I don't understand why it wouldn't generalize to non-isometric mappings. All the same derivatives can be calculated through a spherical projection, for example.

So does arclength hold or not?

[**Note:** when answering this question, feel free to use the example of spherical projections, because it's something I think I understand fairly well. Also, I'm not a mathematician, so formal mathematical language, while likely the most accurate way to answer this question, is probably going to be lost on me.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dot S:=S^2\setminus\{(0,0,1)\}$ be the $2$-sphere with the north pole removed. There is the stereographic projection 
$$\sigma: \quad \dot S\to{\mathbb R}^2,\qquad (x,y,z)\mapsto(\xi,\eta)$$
according to well known formulas. This $\sigma$ is a map of one surface onto another one. It is *not* an isometry when we adopt on $\dot S$ and ${\mathbb R}^2$ their "usual" standard metrics, which come about as follows:

$\dot S$ acquires its standard metric from the embedding of $S^2$ into the euclidean ${\mathbb R}^3$. If $(\phi,\theta)$ are geographical coordinates on $\dot S$ you compute $ds_{\rm sphere}^2=E(\phi,\theta)d\phi^2+G(\phi, \theta)d\theta^2$, whereby $E$ and $G$ in fact depend only on the geographical latitude. On ${\mathbb R}^2$ you have the standard euclidean $ds^2_{\rm plane}=d\xi^2+d\eta^2$.

On $\dot S$ one might think of other coordinate systems, say $(x,y)$ in the vicinity of the south pole, or the $(\xi,\eta)$ furnished by $\sigma$. The latter is to be understood in the following way: Each point $P=(x,y,z)\in\dot S$ so far had geographical coordinates $(\phi,\theta)$, but $P$ obtains now *new* coordinates $(\xi,\eta):=\sigma(P)$. But we do not want to change the length measurement on $\dot S$. This means it is *forbidden* to write $ds^2_{\rm sphere}=d\xi^2+d\eta^2$. Instead we have to do some computation as quoted by you from Wikipedia, and we would then obtain
$$ds^2_{\rm sphere}=G(\xi,\eta)(d\xi^2+d\eta^2)\ .$$
(In this example the resulting transformation formula is so simple because the stereographic projection $\sigma$ is conformal.) Note that in this second thought experiment we have *not* mapped one surface onto another, but we have (for whatever reasons) changed the local coordinate system on the given surface $\dot S$.

Comment: So in both coordinate systems, $(\phi, \theta)$ and $(\xi, \eta)$, the value of $d_{sphere}^2$ will be the same. However, the distance metric $ds_{plane}^2$ is different because it is not an isometric transformation, but rather a projection (a conformal one in this case). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Am I right to then understand that the "arclength being preserved" means that regardless of coordinate system the measure of distance on the parametric surface (e.g. the 2-sphere) will always be the same. Yet, the measure of distance in each coordinate space, however, will not always be (i.e. maybe $d_{plane}^2$ would be different in a different coordinate space?)

Comment: Last followup for now: is a projection not a coordinate system transformation (or reparameterization)?

Comment: @marcman: 1. comment: Basically yes. But $\sigma$ should not be called a "projection", since the word projection is nowadays reserved for projections in cartesian products. – 2. comment: Yes for the first part. "The measure of distance in each coordinate space" makes no sense, only the "measure of distance on a given surface". –3. comment: The formulas are the same, but the interpretation is different. Are we talking about a coordinate transformation in the space $X$ or about a map $f: \>X\to Y$?

Comment: Ahh. When I refer to a projection, I am talking about a map $f : X \rightarrow Y$. Perhaps therein lies the difference. If $f$ is not isometric, then arclength will not hold. If $f$ is isometric, is $f_{isometric} : X \rightarrow Y$ effectively a coordinate transform?

Comment: Perhaps it will help if I shared that I am looking to measure the local ratios $\frac{ds_{surf}}{ds_{plane}}$, where the plane is always a regular Cartesian grid. For example, the way a  cartographic map "projection" can map S2 (or an ellipsoid) to a pixel grid. In my case, it's  not always S2, but some 2D manifold in R3 that I am mapping to a regular grid.

Comment: Last of these second followup questions: a coordinate transform, in this regard, enables the measurement of the surface as a function of a different coordinate system, correct? So the mapping $M: (\phi, \theta) \rightarrow (x,y)$, for example, allows for both the computation of spherical distance as a function of spherical curvilinear coordinates (i.e. $ds_{sphere} = g(\phi, \theta)$) and as a function of rectangular coordinates on some planar map (i.e. $ds_{sphere} = h(x,y)$). Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes. But some computation is needed to transform the metric tensor into the new coordinates.